# call mediator with blocking true property is not working in iterate mediator - wso2 esb 4.9.0/5.00

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to use call mediator with blocking true(I need it for my requirement) and using the call mediator in iterate mediator.

In this way, execution control is not coming out of iterate with aggregate mediator also..

any one has idea how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using this in a "regular" sequence right? 
Could it be an option for you to implement your flow in a proxy so that you've your iterator in the in sequence, you perform send (instead of call) and then in the out sequence you aggregate.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas for the advise but my requriement is to call multiple targets in an iterator and aggregate and all my services are restful and not proxy based services.